# Change color of of a 4th variable in a barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a figure I want to add a different shading for the variable type, so that not only the time frame have its color but also maybe that one type has lines or different patterns to distinguish them.

```
c1 <- c("black", "grey", "white")
df.TS
   NA.       area     species  model time.frame                type
1    1 216755.578        1       base  1970-2000       suitable area
2    2  62223.931        1      base  1970-2000 land use considered
3    3 101675.246        1    SSP126  2021-2040       suitable area
4    4  16033.892        1    SSP126  2021-2040 land use considered
5    5 126760.334        1    SSP245  2021-2040       suitable area
6    6  17153.396        1    SSP245  2021-2040 land use considered
7    7 102700.634        1    SSP370  2021-2040       suitable area
8    8  14025.245        1    SSP370  2021-2040 land use considered
9    9  30015.746        1    SSP126  2041-2060       suitable area
10  10   5286.959        1    SSP126  2041-2060 land use considered
11  11  84113.260        1    SSP245  2041-2060       suitable area
12  12  12538.003        1    SSP245  2041-2060 land use considered
13  13  10159.090        1    SSP370  2041-2060       suitable area
14  14   1885.418        1    SSP370  2041-2060 land use considered

df.TS <- structure(list(NA. = 1:14, area = c(216755.578, 62223.931, 101675.246, 16033.892, 126760.334, 17153.396, 102700.634, 14025.245, 30015.746, 5286.959, 84113.26, 12538.003, 10159.09, 1885.418), species = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), model = c("base", "base", "SSP126", "SSP126", "SSP245", "SSP245", "SSP370", "SSP370", "SSP126", "SSP126", "SSP245", "SSP245", "SSP370", "SSP370"), time.frame = c("1970-2000", "1970-2000", "2021-2040", "2021-2040", "2021-2040", "2021-2040", "2021-2040",  "2021-2040", "2041-2060", "2041-2060", "2041-2060", "2041-2060", "2041-2060", "2041-2060"), type = c("suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered", "suitable area", "land use considered")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```

```
TS<- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df.TS, aes(x=model, y=area, fill=time.frame, color=reorder(type,-area)), position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single"), stat="identity", colour="black",)+
  ggtitle("title") + xlab("model") + ylab("area [ha]")+
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c1)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=11),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 1,),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=11),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",linetype="solid"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "grey"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(linewidth = 0.25, linetype = "solid", colour = "grey"))

TS
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you share your data using `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(df.TS)` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: ahh tank you I´ll remember that for the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ggpattern`.

```r
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(df.TS) +
  geom_col_pattern(data=df.TS, aes(x=model, y=area, fill=time.frame, pattern=type), position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single"), colour="black")+
  ggtitle("title") + xlab("model") + ylab("area [ha]")+
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c1)+
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c("land use considered"="stripe", "suitable area"="none")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=11),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 1,),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=11),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",linetype="solid"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "grey"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(linewidth = 0.25, linetype = "solid", colour = "grey"))
```

[image]

FYI, I suggest using *named* vectors for manual, that way you control which level gets each color regardless of order in the data. For instance,

```r
c1 <- c("1970-2000"="black", "2021-2040"="grey", "2041-2060"="white")
```

It doesn't change anything in this plot (and often won't), but if/when the order of something in your data changes, you'll have no indication other than the colors don't look quite right.